# MS SQL Server Full Text search with JPA and EclipseLink

Tags: sql-server, jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, jpql

MSSQL 2008
EclipseLink 2.3.0
JPA 2.0

I am trying to make an JPQL query to use a fulltext search function of an MSSQL.

as we know that FUNC addictional EclipseLink function doesn't work [1] as it expects the return value, while MSSQL `freetext` [2] is not actually a function but some magic predicate looking like a function [3], I am trying to use the next powerful function mentioned in [4], `SQL`

i tried this

```
and SQL('freetext(?, ?)', d.title, :title)
```

and this

```
and SQL('freetext(?, :title)', d.title)
```

and that combinations with  =1 endings

```
and SQL('freetext(?, ?)', d.title, :title) = 1
```

without any success. it says something like

line 5, column 7: unexpected token [(].
Internal Exception: NoViableAltException(83@[()* loopback of 383:9: (d= DOT right= attribute )*])] with root cause
NoViableAltException(83@[()* loopback of 383:9: (d= DOT right= attribute )*])

where the line 5, column 7 is around the first open parenthesis after SQL keyword.

i am trying to avoid the native SQL as I want to use the advantage of not writing joins with many one-to-many related classes.

what is the correct way to use SQL special function?

[1] [How to use MySQL's full text search from JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186845/how-to-use-mysqls-full-text-search-from-jpa)

[2] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078(v=sql.105).aspx

[3] [Hibernate + MSSQL + Fulltext Search via Contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488094/hibernate-mssql-fulltext-search-via-contains)

[4] http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Support_for_Native_Database_Functions#SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL operator in EclipseLink is new in EclipseLink 2.4.  You need to use the EclipseLink 2.4 milestone or nightly build for this.

If you cannot use 2.4, you can use a native SQL query.

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/milestones.php