# MATCH & AGAINST in Java Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, mysql, full-text-search, spring-data-jpa

I want to use this query: SELECT * FROM USER JOIN USER_CACHE ON USER.ID = USER_CACHE.ID WHERE MATCH (CACHE) AGAINST ( :someText ) > 0 inside the Predicate using Spring Data JPA with Root, CriteriaQuery and CriteriaBuilder classes and add the predicate to a list of predicates that I later condense.

For a while i was using the CONTAINS function, however the database version I updated to no longer supports this procedure.

Is what I am trying to achieve possible?

1. I don't want to use a nativeQuery because I have other search criteria that the user may want to query on besides the search text and too many columns in my table to create unique queries for every combination of variables.
2. I don't want to run multiple queries on the database and filter the result after the fact. It has to be one query or I won't be able to get the code passed inspection.
3. I can't alter the database scheme and can guarantee that the full text index is built and in place.

Database - **Can't change this.**

```
// User Table

ID  | NAME   |  STATUS    |  TYPE
------------------------------------------------------
1   | Dan    | Employed   | Salary
2   | Mark   | Retired    | Salary
3   | Liz    | Temporary  | Hourly
4   | Paul   | Employed   | Salary

// Cache Table

ID  | CACHE *Note: Full Text Search Index
------------------------------------------------------
1   | ID 1 NAME Dan STATUS Employed TYPE Salary
2   | ID 2 NAME Mark STATUS Retired TYPE Salary
3   | ID 3 NAME Liz STATUS Temporary TYPE Hourly
4   | ID 4 NAME Paul STATUS Employed TYPE Salary
```

Java

```
public UserSearchInput class {

    private String searchText; // Full Text Search
    private List<String> userNames;
    private List<String> userStatuses;
    private List<String> userTypes;

    // Get & Set
}

// Specification
public MySearchSpec implements Specification<User> {

    private UserSearchInput searchInput;

    public MySearchSpec(UserSearchInput searchInput){
        this.searchInput = searchInput;
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<User> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        if(searchInput.getSearchText() != null && !searchInput.getSearchText().trim().isEmpty()){

            Root<UserCache> cache = query.from(UserCache.class);

            /*
             *  SELECT * FROM USER 
             *  JOIN USER_CACHE 
             *  ON USER.ID = USER_CACHE.ID
             *  WHERE MATCH (CACHE) AGAINST ('"SEARCH STRING"') > 0;
             */
        }
        if(searchInput.getUserNames() != null && !searchInput.getUserNames().isEmpty()){
            predicates.add(root.get("name").in(searchInput.getUserNames()));
        }
        if(searchInput.getUserStatuses() != null && !searchInput.getUserStatuses().isEmpty()){
            predicates.add(root.get("status").in(searchInput.getUserStatuses());
        }
        if(searchInput.getUserTypes() != null && !searchInput.getUserTypes().isEmpty()){
            predicates.add(root.get("type").in(searchInput.getUserTypes());
        }
        return query.where(cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0])).getRestriction());
    }
}

// Service Method

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepo;

@Async
public Future<List<User>> getUsers(UserSearchInput searchInput, Integer page, Integer size){

    page = page == null || page < 0 ? 0 : page;
    size = size == null || size < 1 ? 100 : size;

    Page<User> userPage = userRepo.findAll(new MySearchSpec(searchInput), new PageRequest(page, size));
    return new AsyncResult<>(userPage.getContent());
}
```

I was reading this post : [How to use MySQL's full text search from JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186845/how-to-use-mysqls-full-text-search-from-jpa) and trying to follow it, but I found a few issues. I need to use EntityManager to set parameters which I can only do when I create the TypedQuery object and pull the results. Additionally doing this will not allow me to use Pagination and my table has way too many results to go without. I thought that I could add a limit, but wasn't too sure how I would grab the next page of results.

Then I thought I could just put the Native SQL inside of the Repository like:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USER " +  
               "JOIN USER_CACHE " +  
               "ON USER.ID = USER_CACHE.ID " +  
               "WHERE MATCH (CACHE) AGAINST (' :searchString ') > 0", 
               nativeQuery = true)
public List<User> fullTextSearch(@Param("searchString") searchString);
```

but the pagination issues still arise. Furthermore I cannot filter by the other search criteria in the RequestBody with this approach.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How do I run the SQL query with Spring Data JPA? Sorry if that was unclear. It's not like other SQL functions that I can just use criteria builder.function with

Comment: The native query route seems like the correct approach since you are trying to use native MySQL functions. Are you facing any problem with the native query?

Comment: If I go that route I cannot filter by the other search criteria inside the request body for example if the user gives me searchText of apples and type of salary there isn't a way that I can easily filter off of both of those together without creating a query for every potential combination. Additionally I don't want to do numerous queries on the database and I want to use pagination.

Comment: Also the real table has over 100 columns and I don't have permission to change the database schemes. I want to use this query inside the Specification/predicate some how and add the criteria to my list of predicates. Is this possible?

Comment: can you add these as questions to the post itself so that they do not get ignored by other readers? Pagination should be easy as you should be able to pass the page number and page size to the `fullTextSearch` method and use them in the query. I still don't follow your comments about *other search criteria*. I am assuming these are specific to your application. I would like to reiterate that if you need/want to use native RDBMS functions, JPA criteria cannot be used to call them. Queries with native functions either need provider support or `EntityManager.createNativeQuery`.

Comment: Sure I'll add them.