# Full Text Search in Spring Boot JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am implementing full text search based on lastName, I am getting below syntax error. Please help me on this

```
public interface FullTextSearchEmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {
        @Query("SELECT emp FROM Employee emp WHERE MATCH (emp.firstName, emp.address, emp.passportNo) AGAINST (:lastName IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)")
        public List<Object[]> findFullTextSearchByLastName(@Param("lastName") String lastName);
    }
```

Below is the syntax error

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:
AGAINST near line 1,  column 217 [SELECT emp FROM com.model.Employee
emp WHERE MATCH (emp.firstName, emp.address, emp.passportNo)  AGAINST
(:lastName IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)]
```

Comment: I will assume it is a mysql database. If you want to use "against" and "match" in the query, I think you should convert to nativeQuery and add this to @Query(value="your query", nativeQuery = true)

Comment: Thank you. After doing nativeQuery = true, I am getting error like could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet"

Comment: This question might enlighten you. https://stackoverflow.com/q/43989817/6332074

Comment: You need also to convert the query to be a native query, with native mysql instead of JPQL

Comment: "SELECT emp" is emp is a column name?

Comment: @RahulKumar here emp is the reference of Emplyee emp entity class

Comment: Brother, Could you please tell me how to convert  it into native query@Query(value = "SELECT emp FROM Employee emp WHERE MATCH (emp.firstName, emp.address, emp.passportNo) AGAINST (:lastName IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)", nativeQuery = true)

Comment: Hi @Pankaj, To convert into nativeQuery, you need to write like the query you run in the mysql database query itself. I can help you if you update the question with the entity class, so I know the table name and column names in the db.

Comment: @Pankaj "SELECT emp" you cannot use emp(reference id) like you have mentioned in the question, you need to do like emp.columnName

Comment: @Rahul Kumar your statement is wrong "you cannot use emp". On JPA you can return only the reference when you need the full object. This was not his problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the comments, JPQL cannot use native functions or keywords from a specific vendor such as MATCH / AGAINST. In order to use such, you need to use native queries:

```
public interface FullTextSearchEmployeeRepository extends 
    JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT emp.* FROM employee emp WHERE MATCH (emp.first_name, emp.address, emp.passport_no) AGAINST (:lastName IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Employee> findFullTextSearchByLastName(@Param("lastName") String lastName);
}
```

NOTE: I am assuming the column names and table name here because they are not present in the question. Feel free to update to the correct ones.
Also, instead of returning an Object[], return the entity itself.

Comment: Hi Brother, I am using below query 
@Query(value = "SELECT emp.* FROM employee emp WHERE MATCH (emp.lastName, emp.first_name, emp.address, emp.passport_no) AGAINST (:lastName IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)", nativeQuery = true)
When I am hitting this URL http://localhost:8080/fullTextSearchByLastName/XYZ in Postman
I am getting other record also which does not have last name as XYZ, as I should get only those records who has last name as XYZ. Thank you

Comment: I am using below classes EmployeeController.java
-----------------------

@GetMapping("/fullTextSearchByLastName/{lastName}")
    public List<Employee> fullTextSearchByLastName(@PathVariable("lastName") String lastName){
        return employeeService.getFullTextSearchByLastName(lastName);
    }

Comment: EmployeeService.java
--------------------

  public List<Employee> getFullTextSearchByLastName(String lastName){
        return employeeRepository.findFullTextSearchByLastName(lastName);
    }

Comment: FullTextSearchEmployeeRepository.java
-------------------------------------

public interface FullTextSearchEmployeeRepository extends 
    JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT emp.* FROM employee emp WHERE MATCH (emp.lastName, emp.first_name, emp.address, emp.passport_no) AGAINST (:lastName IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Employee> findFullTextSearchByLastName(@Param("lastName") String lastName);
}

Comment: Hi Brother, I am getting records which having last name as AXK, AYK, AZK, XAZ, ZYB, BXY. We should get only those records which having last name as XYZ. Thank you

Comment: hi @Pankaj, If possible, try to execute the query straight in the database to see the results, if they still come wrongly, then the query is not ok. Another point, is "emp.lastName" correct? Shouldn't be "emp.last_name" following the convention for the other fields?

Comment: Can you try "IN BOOLEAN MODE" instead of "IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE" and add "+" to the lastName before searching, like this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Answer (score 0):

Queries in `@Query` annotations of Spring Data JPA are assumed to be JPQL queries.
JPQL does not support full text search.

You can set `nativeQuery=true` if you want to use SQL (in the dialect of the database you are using), but this still doesn't look like a valid query, because your select list contains the table alias, which is fine in JPQL but SQL requires a list of expressions (columns most of the time) or a `*`.