# DB query match on string split into unordered categories

Tags: mysql, postgresql, spring-data, hql

What is best way to find in DB results given only string which can contain in random order name, surname, description, phone, id

I also want to make sure that all values from query param are used for any selected row.

Example:

```
+--------+---------+-------------+----------+-----+
| Name   | Surname | Description |  Phone   | Id  |
+--------+---------+-------------+----------+-----+
| John   | Doe     | Tall        | 12345678 | 123 |
| Taylor | Doe     | Short       | 45678913 | 234 |
| Taylor | Joe     | Short       | 45678913 | 345 |
+--------+---------+-------------+----------+-----+
```

Query -> result:

- `Jo` -> John Doe and Taylor Joe
- `Ta Do` -> John Doe, Taylor Doe and Taylor Joe
- `Taylor 234` -> Taylor Doe
- `Doe 23` -> John Doe and Taylor Doe
- `Doe 123` -> John Doe
- `Doe 234` ->

I need query in HQL but I believe solution in any relational DB language would help me greatly.

@edit if you down vote please comment why (bad tags? no possible solution?)

Answer (score 2):

The solution is as simple as it is unsatisfying. Create a query with a where clause like this

```
WHERE (columnA like '%value1%' 
    OR columnB '%value1%') 
AND (columnA '%value2%' 
    OR columnB '%value2%')
AND (...
) ...
```

with all combinations of columns you want to search and values you have.

With Spring Data you probably want to use a [`Specification`](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) to do this. You would create a method that creates a `Specification` equivalent to the query condition above by taking your query string, splitting it on the white space and iterating over the result.

Note that this will be very slow since it won't be able to use any normal index.

But really you are using the wrong tool for the job. Which is ok if this is a one of thing you need to implement. A better tool would be a search engine like Lucene, or possibly [text search features in your database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html). For the integration of this with JPA see [How to use MySQL's full text search from JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186845/how-to-use-mysqls-full-text-search-from-jpa).

If you considere a full blown search engine you might consider [Spring Data Elastic Search](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/)

Comment: But as far as I understand this doesn't check if all chunks of search query were matched. So in your solution `Doe 123` would return both John Doe and Taylor Doe. I understand that performance wouldn't be best but for now  I need to deliver POC of app and don't have time to research how to integrate more aproparete solution or infrastructure to host it (as I understand most of such solutions are pretty memory hungry). Other problem is how I can iterate on all values in query (I don't know number so value1, and so on is not possible unless I create n functions each taking different # of params)

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: still no hint how to deal with unknown number or values user entered or how I can convert single string provided by user to separate values. I guess I could do it on higher level but then do I have one query with say 10 values and pass not used values as empty strings?

Comment: It's in the answer: "With Spring Data you probably want to use a Specification to do this. You would create a method that creates a Specification equivalent to the query condition above by taking your query string, splitting it on the white space and iterating over the result." Along with a link to an article how Specifications work.